# How can I trigger Xunit tests from console automatically aftter e certain process has finished?

Tags: c#, console, xunit

I have an XUnit project set up. Is there a possibility to run this outside Visual Studio?

I have understood that I need to find the `XUnit Console.exe` i have tried to find this in my local path:
`C:\Users\RLEBEDEVS\.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.console\2.4.1`. I only see `.net742` there, though my project is in `.Net Core`.

How would I run the test like this or similar?

Regards,

Comment: If you have dotnet cli tool, you can type `dotnet test` to run your tests on the terminal.

Comment: `dotnet test`, where the project is located?

Comment: You can specify the sln or csproj with this command. For more information you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `@Engincan Veske`, the solution was indeed to run dotnet test

1. Navigated to the folder of the project via CMD
2. Run `dotnet test <.cproj name>`

This executed the unit tests.

Regards,